# Check new element in the Grid Plugin ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridview, grid, extjs4.2

I have  a grid which uses the grid plugin from here

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html

the grid i use is the second one with the possibility to check and uncheck all elements from it.

When i add a new element in the grid it is not selected, and i need it to be selected. Here is what i do.

```
 var split = record.copy();
            Ext.data.Model.id(split);

split.set(Constant.Docdef.ByName.POSITION_NUMBER
.
.
.
split.set(Constant.Docdef.ByName.IS_NEW, 1); 

// add it to the store
store.insert(rowIndex + totalSplits, split);
```

Now the problem is that i copy a selected record, but when i add it to the grid it is not selected.

Has anyone any idea how i can achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the selection isn't done by the store, but with help of the gridpanel's selectionModel. You need to add the record to the selection:

```
var selectionModel = gridpanel.getSelectionModel();

//only if you want to check if the original was selected
if (selectionModel.isSelected(record) == true) {
    selectionModel.select(split, true);
}
```

Comment: Tiny correction: isSelected function returns a boolean. Your true check is not needed.

Comment: @Ee-P: Why don't you mention that the Curly Braces aren't needed too so we can write everything in one line? For me in javascript it's cleaner to see the two sides in a condition, it's coding style...